# randomly generate a sequence either -1 or 1 in an array

Tags: java, random

need to Print the spin configuration at each step in for loop
So for n = 4 configuration we can have

```
 1     1    1     1            
 1     1   -1     1           
-1     1   -1     1           
-1     1   -1     1            
-1    -1   -1     1
```

I need to randomly generate 1 or -1 if n = 4 have an array of length 4 of 1 or -1 and you can have up to 2^n in this case 2^4 possible configuration. 
Need to print out these possible configuration. Not sure how to go about this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println(randomOneOrMinusOne());

        }
    }

    static int randomOneOrMinusOne() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        if (rand.nextBoolean())
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. Are you trying to print out all possible sequences? For example, if I input "3", I get `{ {-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1} }`?

Comment: Your code already prints four random one-or-minus-ones. What is your question? Do you want to print all possible combinations? If so, that is as far from random as possible.

Comment: Don't keep creating new instances of `Random`. It's not "more random" to do this. Create one and reuse it.

Comment: Since you need to generate all possible sequences, there is no question about random at all. All possible sequences will take care of randomness anyway. Each location has either -1 or 1 and this is more of an algorithm question.

Comment: @vivek_23 ok so if each location gets -1 or 1 then can I generate a random sequence first then alter each position. so for n =2 i will have say randomly generated 1 1 then i can go modify first position to -1 and leave second to 1 and get -1 1 then try modifying -1 1 and get -1 -1 but this seems very complicated

Comment: @BretC yes i am trying to print possible sequences

Answer (score 1):

This works by going through each of the 2^n combinations seeing which bits in the combination is set. If a bit is set, put a '1' in the array, otherwise put a '-1' in.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class AllSeq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get the number of elements from args or default to 4
        int n = args.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 4;

        // Work out total number of combinations (2^n)
        BigInteger combinations = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(n);

        // For each combination...
        for(BigInteger i = BigInteger.ZERO; i.compareTo(combinations) < 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            // Initialise an array with 'n' elements
            int[] resultForThisCombination = new int[n];

            // We now go through each bit in the combination...
            for(int bit = 0; bit < n; bit++) {
                BigInteger bitValue = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(bit);

                // If the bit is set, set array element to 1 else set it to -1...
                if(i.and(bitValue).equals(bitValue)) {
                    resultForThisCombination[bit] = 1;
                } else {
                    resultForThisCombination[bit] = -1;
                }
            }

            // Print result / do whatever with it
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultForThisCombination));
        }
    }
}
```

If you put in a big number for n, you may be waiting some time...

If n is never more than 63 (if you ever want to wait that long!!), you can use a long instead of a BigInteger.

Comment: got it, also Bret if i wanted to get the sum of say 4 combination can I get the sum within this for(int bit = 0; bit < n; bit++) {
                BigInteger bitValue = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(bit);

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = generateSequences(4);
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();++i){
            System.out.println(result.get(i).toString());
        }
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> generateSequences(int seq_size){
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

        // for our recursion base case
        if(seq_size == 1){
            List<Integer> new_seq_1 = new ArrayList<>(); // add -1 once 
            new_seq_1.add(-1);
            List<Integer> new_seq_2 = new ArrayList<>(); // add 1 once
            new_seq_2.add(1);
            result.add(new_seq_1);
            result.add(new_seq_2);
            return result;
        }

        List<List<Integer>> sub_ans = generateSequences(seq_size - 1);

        for(int i=0;i<sub_ans.size();++i){
            List<Integer> new_seq_1 = new ArrayList<>(sub_ans.get(i)); // add -1 once 
            new_seq_1.add(-1);
            List<Integer> new_seq_2 = new ArrayList<>(sub_ans.get(i)); // add 1 once
            new_seq_2.add(1);
            result.add(new_seq_1);
            result.add(new_seq_2);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[-1, -1, -1, -1]
[-1, -1, -1, 1]
[-1, -1, 1, -1]
[-1, -1, 1, 1]
[-1, 1, -1, -1]
[-1, 1, -1, 1]
[-1, 1, 1, -1]
[-1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, -1, -1, -1]
[1, -1, -1, 1]
[1, -1, 1, -1]
[1, -1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, -1, -1]
[1, 1, -1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, -1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

**Algorithm:**

- We can do this recursively.
- So, for every position, we can have a -1 or 1. Since you want all possible sequences, we need to take -1 **and** 1.
- So, if size is `1`, the `2` possibilities are `[-1]` and `[1]`.
- Let's trace through an example for possibilities for sequence of size `2`.

  - For size = 1 => [-1],[1]
  - For size = 2, add `-1` to all previous possibilities and also add `1` to previous possibilities. So, we will have

    - [-1,-1]
    - [1, -1]
    - [-1,1]
    - [1,1]
- Likewise, every new possibility depends on it's subset possibilities and adding curr element to each possibility generates current new possibilities/sequences.

Comment: Make sense, also if i wanted to get the sum of the total combination can I simply iterate through the list for example of size 2 i'll iterate through [-1 -1] and store sum of -2 then go to next combination [1 -1] sum of -2 + 0 and next combination [-1 1] sum of -2 + 0 + 0 and last configuration [1 1] with sum of -2 + 0 + 0 + 2 = 0 Thank you

Comment: @AnikSarder Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Improving slightly on [@BretC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54690972/7099148), we can avoid creating quite as many BigIntegers and doing bitmask operations:

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class AllSeq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get the number of elements from args or default to 4
        int n = args.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 4;

        // Work out total number of combinations (2^n)
        BigInteger bitValue = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(n);
        int firstOne = n-1;

        // For each combination...
        while(firstOne >= 0) {
            bitValue = bitValue.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
            firstOne = bitValue.getLowestSetBit()

            // Initialise an array with 'n' elements all set to -1
            int[] resultForThisCombination = new int[n];
            Arrays.fill(resultForThisCombination, -1);

            if(firstOne >= 0) {
                // We now go through each bit in the combination...
                for(int bit = firstOne; bit < n; bit++) {
                // If the bit is set, set array element to 1 else set it to -1...
                    if(bitValue.testBit(bit)) {
                        resultForThisCombination[bit] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Print result / do whatever with it
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultForThisCombination));
        }
    }
}
```